# Is there a Visual Studio Code equivalent to eclipse's Infinitest?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, visual-studio-code, infinitest

I would like to do (Java) TDD in Visual Studio Code. I have experience with this in eclipse using JUnit4 and Infinitest.

JUnit4 is available for VS Code, but I would also like to have the Infinitest functionality (continuous test running), however I can't seem to find a plugin that does this.

Is there an option in JUnit4 or some other tool that could automatically run my tests like Infinitest?

Comment: Well. Looks like currently this kind of extension does not exist. VS Code itself does not contain such a tool.